# how to get timeline back

Tags: animation

Lost the timeline bar. and can't get it back.[image]

Comment: You should be able to drag it back up.

Comment: OK, I had to change the editor type too.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also create multiple timelines (if needed) or create a new one by sliding the scene left or right from one of the bottom corners. This will create a new view of a editor. Where the triangle lines are.[image]